# Laravel Forge error installing Github Repository Error

Tags: laravel, forge, laravel-forge

I was trying to sync my github repository with laravel forge but i am getting an error and can't seem to fix it. When i tried to sync another project everything worked fine but it just this one project that does not seem to be working. Not sure if it a dependency or a package that is causing the error. At the bottom of the error `user 'forge'@'localhost'`. But in my other projects in the database.php file i never changed anything in it. Not sure if it a ssh error can someone help me?

```
Cloning into 'default'...
Checking out files:  41% (4480/10887)   
Checking out files:  42% (4573/10887)   
Checking out files:  43% (4682/10887)   
Checking out files:  44% (4791/10887)   
Checking out files:  45% (4900/10887)   
Checking out files:  46% (5009/10887)   
Checking out files:  47% (5117/10887)   
Checking out files:  48% (5226/10887)   
Checking out files:  49% (5335/10887)   
Checking out files:  50% (5444/10887)   
Checking out files:  51% (5553/10887)   
Checking out files:  52% (5662/10887)   
Checking out files:  53% (5771/10887)   
Checking out files:  54% (5879/10887)   
Checking out files:  55% (5988/10887)   
Checking out files:  56% (6097/10887)   
Checking out files:  57% (6206/10887)   
Checking out files:  58% (6315/10887)   
Checking out files:  59% (6424/10887)   
Checking out files:  60% (6533/10887)   
Checking out files:  61% (6642/10887)   
Checking out files:  62% (6750/10887)   
Checking out files:  63% (6859/10887)   
Checking out files:  64% (6968/10887)   
Checking out files:  65% (7077/10887)   
Checking out files:  66% (7186/10887)   
Checking out files:  67% (7295/10887)   
Checking out files:  68% (7404/10887)   
Checking out files:  69% (7513/10887)   
Checking out files:  70% (7621/10887)   
Checking out files:  71% (7730/10887)   
Checking out files:  72% (7839/10887)   
Checking out files:  73% (7948/10887)   
Checking out files:  74% (8057/10887)   
Checking out files:  75% (8166/10887)   
Checking out files:  76% (8275/10887)   
Checking out files:  77% (8383/10887)   
Checking out files:  78% (8492/10887)   
Checking out files:  79% (8601/10887)   
Checking out files:  80% (8710/10887)   
Checking out files:  81% (8819/10887)   
Checking out files:  82% (8928/10887)   
Checking out files:  83% (9037/10887)   
Checking out files:  84% (9146/10887)   
Checking out files:  85% (9254/10887)   
Checking out files:  86% (9363/10887)   
Checking out files:  87% (9472/10887)   
Checking out files:  88% (9581/10887)   
Checking out files:  89% (9690/10887)   
Checking out files:  90% (9799/10887)   
Checking out files:  91% (9908/10887)   
Checking out files:  92% (10017/10887)   
Checking out files:  93% (10125/10887)   
Checking out files:  94% (10234/10887)   
Checking out files:  95% (10343/10887)   
Checking out files:  96% (10452/10887)   
Checking out files:  97% (10561/10887)   
Checking out files:  98% (10670/10887)   
Checking out files:  99% (10779/10887)   
Checking out files: 100% (10887/10887)   
Checking out files: 100% (10887/10887), done.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Package phpoffice/phpexcel is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use phpoffice/phpspreadsheet instead.
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover

In PDOConnection.php line 50:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using pa  
  ssword: NO)                                                                  


In PDOConnection.php line 46:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using pa  
  ssword: NO)                                                                  


Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

Comment: You have to set the db credentials in the `.env` file for the database you want to use. If the DB is on the same server then I would assume from the error that the password hasn't been set in your `.env` file.

Comment: @RossWilson I thought i setup my env file once laravel forge has done installing from github. But your saying before i install i have to setup my .env file interesting.

Comment: No, you shouldn't need to do that. Did you install the repo through the Forge dashboard or manually?

Comment: @RossWilson i tried to install from forge dashboard